# Excel Macro date format changing on file open

Tags: excel, vba

I have a weird problem, whenever I open my csv file into excel manually, the dates appear correctly formatted in UK locale - dd/mm/yyyy. However, I have a macro which opens up my csv file, and I get some dates formatted in as mm/dd/yyyy and others formatted as dd/mm/yyyy. The pattern seems to be the ones which are incorrect seems to be when the is a single digit for the day so 05/11/2012 is now appearing as 11/05/2012, but 15/11/2012 is appearing exactly as the csv file.

Any help would be great.

Thanks
Jalz

```
Sub openfile()
'
' openfile Macro
'

   Workbooks.Open filename:= _
    "c:\myfile.csv"
   Range("A1:J46").Select
   Selection.Copy
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @JK63.  What do you mean with manually opening the CSV?  Does it mean open excel and pasting the values or right clicking the file and selecting open with MsExcel?

Comment: No I mean I load excel up and then go to file open and select my cab file. All dates are in the correct order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VBA uses the default local of USA,( even if you are in a diferent locale) with all the formatting set to it(date separators, decimal separators). You can bypass it with the local attribute:

```
  Call Workbooks.Open(Filename:="c:\myfile.csv", local:=True)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks kurast, Just had a chance to look at it again with your code above, not doing anything fancy, just opening the file and its still got dates mixed up when i run that macro.... If I go to File open, the file opens and displays the correct range of dates....

Comment: Could you record (macro recorder) what happens when you mannualy open the csv file?

Comment: Hi kurast, I think its working - I was working with some old data which I had 'changed' to figure out what excel was doing and forgot about it. im running some more tests Thanks again